# What is the dimension of a array with 4 brackets

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

say I have an array like:

```
       double theArray[2][5][3][4];
```

I don't quite understand the last dimension.

```
 first is [][][][][]

 second is [][][][][]
           [][][][][]

 third would make it 3 dimensional,
```

what would the fourth do?

Comment: Not to confuse the dimension of array to dimensions in physical reality a.k.a. x, y, and z. The 4th dimension is not necessarily the "time" :-)

Comment: Make it an abstract 4 dimensional hypercube

Comment: Think of it this way.  You have a 3 dimensional array.  Now get a bunch of those and stick their pointers into an array.  That's 4 dimensions.  You understand the 3-dimensional array, and the 4th dimension is just a collection of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ (like C before it) doesn't really have multidimensional arrays, so none of them is really 2, 3, 4 (etc.) dimensional.

Rather, what C++ provides is arrays, arrays of arrays, etc. With four sets of brackets, you have an array of arrays of arrays of arrays.

Now, forget that I said any of that -- using arrays in C++ is rarely a good idea, and using arrays of arrays is generally even worse. A psuedo-4D array as you've shown above is many times worse still. Just don't do it.

If you need to imitate a 2D, 3D, etc., array, use a class. It makes life dramatically simpler.

Comment: C++ and C really do have multidimensional arrays. They just happen to be defined as arrays of arrays.

Comment: Just a note, you can do a 2D array using a 1D shorthand, `x + y * w`.  x,y the coordinates, and `w`, the width of the array.

Answer (score 4):

The fourth dimension is **time**. Together with three spatial dimensions it forms **spacetime**.

Comment: I would suggest that the fourth dimension is *typically* time.  It could be something else, depending on the problem being modeled.

Comment: @PeterGluck I hope you are not suggesting for us to go below `Plank length` into string theory ;)?.. It just occurred to me that OP was asking about physical representation rather than C++. After all, in C++ if you understand 2D arrays, you understand nD arrays as well...

Comment: For a C or C++ array, the fourth dimension is simply the fourth dimension. Whether it corresponds to time is entirely up to the chosen semantics of the program. The language assigns no meaning to the dimensions of an array beyond the way the array is laid out in memory and its elements are accessed.

Comment: No, not suggesting that, just that someone may be modelling something else (say a network).  Any problem space with N independent variables could be represented using an N-dimensional matrix.

Comment: I suggest that if what you, guys, talking about was the case, the OP would not have a problem figuring out what the fourth dimension is (or 43rd). The problem for OP (as it seems to me) is that he can picture 3 dimensions visually as spatial dimensions (despite the fact that he didn't know how to "draw" 3rd dimension in his post). But he could not picture the fourth dimension... I thought, I'd point him in the direction where he can learn something about it...

Answer (score 1):

```
double theArray[2] ==> [][]

double theArray[2][5] ==> [][], [][], [][], [][], [][]

double theArray[2][5][3] ==> [][], [][], [][], [][], [][]
                             [][], [][], [][], [][], [][]
                             [][], [][], [][], [][], [][]

double theArray[2][5][3][4] ==> .............
```

Comment: I thought you are going to complete the visual representation :-)

Comment: I actually recall a Visual Studio extension that visualizes arrays. I think it does 4D with N cubes.

Answer (score 1):

In both C and C++, a 2-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays -- nothing more, nothing less.

A 3-dimensional array is an array of arrays of arrays.

What you have:

```
double theArray[2][5][3][4];
```

is a 4-dimensional array, an array of arrays of arrays of arrays.

If you're thinking in terms of spatial dimensions, there isn't necessarily any physical significance to *any* of the dimensions of an array. They're simply ordered sequences of elements, where the sequences may themselves be sequences, and so on.

There is no limit (other than compile-time and run-time storage space, and *maybe* some arbitrary limit imposed by a compiler) on the number of dimensions an array can have.

For a 2-dimensional array, you can think of the elements being laid out in a rectangular grid:

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

but in fact the whole thing is linear, with each row immediately following the previous one in memory.

```
[][][][][][][][][][][][]
- row0 -- row1- - row2 -
```

You can also build other data structures that act like multi-dimensional arrays.  If you use pointers, arrays of pointers, and so forth, then the elements and rows may be scattered arbitrarily through memory. But that doesn't really matter for most purposes.

Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) has a very good discussion of the often confusing relationship between arrays and pointers in C, most of which also applies to C++.

C++ provides other data structures, as part of the standard library, that are more flexible and robust than C-style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we want use multi-dimension array to track world population.

```
// Population per country: 
int population[ C ]; 
// the 1st dimension is the country index, C is the number of countries

// Population per country per state: 
int population[ C ][ S ];
// the 2nd dimension is the state index, S is the max number of states per cuntry

// Population per country per state per county: 
int population[ C ][ S ][ N ];
// the 3rd dimension is the county index, N is the max number of county per state

// Population per country per state per county per city: 
int population[ C ][ S ][ N ][ I ];
// the 4th dimension is the city index, I is the max number of city per county

// Population per country per state per county per city per gender

// Population per country per state per county per city per gender per age-group
```

Note: This is just an example, it is certainly not the best way to model the population.

Note 2: See Jerry Coffin's answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I you want a trick to get to visualize what are 4 dimensional array (4 dimensional matrix in math terms) you could just represent it as an  array of cubes (rectangular parallelepipeds to be more accurate if the dimension are not equal).

Just as a 3 dimensional array could be represented as an array of matrix